# Problem: qqplot legend different linetypes

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

```
legend <- c("score" = "black", "answer" = "red")

plot <- df_l %>% ggplot(aes(date, score, color = "score")) + geom_line() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = getDate(df_all %>% filter(name == List[5])), color = "answer"), linetype = "dashed", size = 1,) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = legend) +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%y"), breaks = date_breaks("months")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45)) +
  labs(title = "", x = "", y = "", colors = "Legend")
```

[image]

I get the result above and could not figure out how to resolve the problem that in the legend always both lines are mixed up. One legend should of course show the slim black line only and the other the dashed black line. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that `geom_vline` results in a legend item that is a vertical line and `geom_line` gives you a horizontal line item.  One solution is to create the legend kind of manually by specifying the `color=` aesthetic in `geom_line`... but *not* in `geom_vline`.  You can then create a kind of "dummy" geom with `geom_blank` that serves as a holding object for the aesthetics of `color=`.  You can then specify the colors for both of those items via `scale_color_manual`.  Here's an example:

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=rnorm(100))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(aes(color='score')) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=4), linetype=2, color='red', show.legend = FALSE) +

  geom_blank(aes(color='my line')) +

  scale_color_manual(name='Legend', values=c('my line'='red','score'='black'))
```

[image]

That creates the one legend for color... but unfortunately "my line" is solid red, when it should be dashed.  To fix that, you just apply the `linetype=` aesthetic in the same way.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(aes(color='score', linetype='score')) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=4), linetype=2, color='red', show.legend = FALSE) +

  geom_blank(aes(color='my line', linetype='my line')) +

  scale_linetype_manual(name='Legend', values=c('my line'=2,'score'=1)) +
  scale_color_manual(name='Legend', values=c('my line'='red','score'='black'))
```

[image]